# Can I be a professor just by publishing scientific papers and teach 2 or 3 courser per year without writing a proposal (Electrical Engineering)

Tags: academic-life, productivity

I am an academia person having some good publication records. It seems that I may need to spend most of my time in writing proposal if I join as a university faculty in North America.

I have reservations on two aspects of the proposal writing:

Worthiness:

Does a proposal evaluate the true skill of the candidate? My answer (with high probability) is No. This is because, if the candidate is an excellent one, his knowledge is exploited in several of his past academic records. The first is his publication record (especially from the reputable journals). This record (along with the review comments) will almost show the true skill of the candidate. And I did not see a reason to ask the candidate to submit an extra cover letter (proposal).

To my knowledge, the proposal is the very important component for funding. And I am not aware of any colleague getting funding just by submitting his/her CV?

Please note that if the idea of the proposal is shiny (evaluated by experts in the same area only), it should be publishable as a technical paper.

Evaluation Method:

It is known that funding agencies require proposals to provide support for research. However, most of the evaluators of the proposal are not working in the same research area, and in most cases they fail to understand the true contribution of the proposal especially if it is a deep rooted concept. Thus, such a system will benefit those who are not knowledgeable in their research area which I believe is a bit unfair. One may claim that that the reason could be a luck of expertise in the area. However, this can be circumvented by requesting detailed information about the candidate. For example, one of them is by checking the peer review comments of the previously published papers from the reputable journals.

It looks that these evaluation approaches are not integrated in the current system for the reason that I did not understand especially in the academic environment. And I prefer not to involve in such kind of competition. I am also not interested to perform some administrative works such as department recruiting as these activities have their own complications.

I am a bit fan of doing research and teach few courses per year, and organizing conferences, workshops, and peer reviewing papers. Thus, my question is that is there any institution who can hire professors so that their responsibility is just publishing scientific papers and teach 2 or 3 courser per year without writing a proposal (Electrical Engineering)?

Thanks for reading this long question.

Comment: Well... is  your research such that you can carry it out and publish papers without any funding?

Comment: Oh, and: *I am also not interested to perform some administrative works such as department recruiting as these activities have their own complications.* I think that alone rules out all positions in the US having the word "professor" in their title.  Likely other countries too, but I couldn't say for sure.

Comment: Dear Sir,

Thank you for providing the answer. I strongly support the idea that a university professor should be funded. What I did not agree is the way a professor is evaluated to get a fund. I have the same reason for the department recruitment issues. It is not because I simply dislike it, it is just because I did not support the way it should be (like funding).

Comment: As with previous "questions" of this OP, this is a poorly disguised rant against the way grant proposals are evaluated.

Comment: Do you want a pony with that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it describes a proposal/suggestion (to whom?) instead of a question looking for an answer.

Comment: If your field is pure math, yes, it is possible. You don't need funding. All you need is pencil and paper to do research. You can fund your students by giving them TA. You say your field is EE, then you have serious problem. You need lab. You need equipment. You need to hire people to maintain the lab. You and your students need to use the lab to do research. How can you do your job without funding? Where would the funding come from? You need to write proposal to get it. Nothing comes free. There is no free lunch!

Comment: The question is posed from a perspective of almost complete ignorance. To think that the evaluators of proposals are ignorant about the proposals they evaluate makes no sense. In truth, the people who review proposals are typically among the best in their field, and they understand a great deal about what is being proposed.

Comment: I'm also going to add that it is simply not true that professors spend "most of their time" writing proposals.

Comment: Dear  Wolfgang Bangerth,
Thank you for replying. I am not ignoring the people effort in evaluating the proposals. I understand that the evaluators are experts in the area and they are doing their best to get the best candidate. However, given the vast majority of disciplines (I know in EE), it is almost impossible to sharply understand the true contribution of the proposal unless the evaluator is working in the exactly the same area. The other thing is: Is it really important for a professor to write a proposal to get grant?

Comment: Why did not he/she spend the same time to contribute to the scientific community a new article. This will add value to the scientific community.
I have also many experiences from friends (and mine) stating that your CV is excellent but you do not get scholarship/funding just because of luck of “not-so-good proposal”. And the people who get award do not have strong CV like me. One of my professor said me that, these days it is better to improve your skill on how to “sell yourself” rather than doing excellent technical paper.

Comment: I also know how much tough for a person to get an accepted paper in reputable journals of IEEE (in such a case the reviewers will see the true technical contribution of the paper rather than how you present it). Also they will give you a chance to explain your technical contribution (and in most cases the paper will not be accepted if the contribution is not enough).

Comment: "given the vast majority of disciplines" -- yet again, you insist on claiming something is universal but don't indicate any supporting evidence. Once again I'd like to point out that there are many different subjects and disciplines that make up academia, and many different countries in which academic research takes place

Answer (score 7):

If you can do your research without funding, than sure. However, even in "cheap" fields professors are expected to train PhD students, and these are expensive, so hard to get without funding.

As to administrative duties; universities are typically "self-administered". That is good, as that way we make our own decisions and not some external bureaucrat. But that also means that we need to do that.

Think of it this way: everywhere where people make a career (in academia and elsewhere), their set of duties change from substantive to increasingly bureaucratic duties. If you don't like that, then don't make a career.

Comment: Dear All
Thank you again for answering my question. As mentioned in the question, professors must get funding to do research. In fact, it is impossible to perform any kind of research (at least in EE) without getting any fund. What I am questioning is the way a professor is getting funding?
According to one of my questions (why prof spend more time in writing proposals), there is a consensus in these two issues: 
1. Professors usually prefer to spend more time in their research area
2. Professors do not have any other choice other than spending their time in writing a proposal.

Comment: This will ultimately affect the overall productivity of the academic environment. The 10% success rate of a proposal makes things even worse. 

If what I am stating is correct with high probability, why do not the academic society create a scheme to provide funding without writing a proposal (for example just by CV). To my knowledge, I did not see any effort in this direction. 

In my opinion, it is sad that we all academicians accept proposal which is an “infertile culture” as a norm to get funding.

Comment: Please note that the academic environment should be a place where people will debate their ideas, learn new things, show their intellectual ability, develop their thought etc. I think these are the pillars for a university professor/graduate students/postdocs to work with low salary (compared to most other disciplines).

I would appreciate to get more details if I misunderstood something.

Comment: NOTE: I am not ignoring the people effort in evaluating the a professor's outcome to provide funding (I would also do the same if I would have been in their place). But what I am suggesting is a new way of Evaluation.

Comment: @AngryAcademia: Well, that is not what you asked.  You asked whether it is possible to hold a professorship without writing proposals, and the effective answer is no, it is not possible in today's world.  If you want to propose alternative models and discuss their pros and cons, that is great, but this site is not the place for it: here we are focused on question with answers, not ongoing debates.

Comment: As you move up on the hierarchy of any organization you will be more involved in the planning and less in the actual production. In academia that is organized in such a way that professors write proposals to fund PhD students and postdocs who do most of the research. While it is true that the professor could probably do each single task faster than those students or postdocs, they would not have the time to do all those tasks. Moreover, they also serve the purpose of training the next generation of researchers. So I don't see anything wrong with this division of labor.

Comment: On a practical/political level: it is not our money. The tax payers deserve a level of accountability. It is more sensible to distribute money based on what you want to do with it than on what you have done in the past.

Comment: Writing proposals is not lost effort, even if it is rejected. Those tend to come back in one form or another in other proposals.

Comment: @AngryAcademia It seems that although you are asking questions, what you really want to do is to tell us your own answers, or have a debate. If that is the case, then I suggest that your own blog or some similar forum would be more suitable. StackExchange sites are not meant as places for extended debate, or reiteration of one's own views in the guise of rhetorical question